# Unknown provider: uniqueFilterProvider using unique filter in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ngselect

I am new to AngularJS. I am trying to implement filtering to build a unique list of options for the select box. My code is as follows

```
<select name="show-filter" id="show-filter" ng-model="card" ng-options="v for v in currentOptions.cards  | unique:'cardno'">
<option value="">All</option>
</select>
```

I am getting the following error

> Error: Unknown provider: uniqueFilterProvider <- uniqueFilter

sample JSON (wrapped into `$scope.currentOptions`)

```
"cards ":[{"cardno":"123223333"},{"cardno":"123223333"},{"cardno":"123223333"}]}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AngularJS does not have a built-in `unique` filter. You may be looking for the third-party add-on library called [AngularUI](http://angular-ui.github.io/) that does have such a filter.

Comment: i have used this <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui/0.4.0/angular-ui.min.js"></script> .when i put this one i am getting Uncauangular is not defined(anonymous function) @ angular-ui.min.js:7
angul