# How to generate BS accordion from JSON with ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have JSON:

```
$scope.allTags=[
        {id: 1, name: 'name1', description: 'description1', title: 'title1'},
        {id: 2, name: 'name2', description: 'description1', title: 'title1'},
        {id: 3, name: 'name3', description: 'description2', title: 'title2'},
        {id: 4, name: 'name4', description: 'description2', title: 'title2'},
        {id: 5, name: 'name5', description: 'description3', title: 'title3'},
        {id: 6, name: 'name6', description: 'description3', title: 'title3'},
        {id: 7, name: 'name7', description: 'description3', title: 'title3'},
    ];
```

And I need to create BS accordion like this:

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#tags-accordion" href="#col_Iesaukumi1">Title1</a></br>
<div id="col_Iesaukumi1" class="collapse">
    <span>name1</span><span>name2</span>
</div>
<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#tags-accordion" href="#col_Iesaukumi2">Title2</a></br>
<div id="col_Iesaukumi2" class="collapse">
    <span>name3</span><span>name4</span>
</div><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#tags-accordion" href="#col_Iesaukumi3">Title3</a></br>
<div id="col_Iesaukumi3" class="collapse">
    <span>name5</span><span>name6</span>span>name7</span>
</div>
```

And its killing me. I am new to angular and strugle with this task. In plain JS I did something like this:

```
    var prev = null;
    var counter = 1;
    for(var i = 0; i < allTags.length; i++){
        if(prev != allTags[i].title){
            if(prev != null){
                html += '</div>';
            }
            html += '<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#tags-accordion" href="#col_collapse'+counter+'">'+allTags[i].title+'</a><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="'+allTags[i].description+'"><i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></br>';
            html+='<div id="col_collapse'+counter+'" class="collapse">';
            prev = allTags[i].title;
            counter++;
        }
        html += '<span class="tagi" data-type="tags" data-value="'+allTags[i].id+'">'+allTags[i].name+'</span>';
    }
    html += '</div>';
```

However I can not understand how use this tech with angular.

Comment: just save the template you are making ( "html" variable) in html page itself and use ng-repeat like this : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: Ofcourse, that exactly what I am trying to do. The logic in this template is much harder than in basic ng-repeat examples. In my pure JS example I have checked if title have changed, if so then close previous div and start drawing next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```
<a ng-repeat-start="tag in allTags | unique:'description'" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#tags-accordion" href="#col_Iesaukumi{{$index}}">
{{tag.title}}
</a></br>
<div ng-repeat-end id="col_Iesaukumi{{$index}}" class="collapse">
    <span ng-repeat="n in allTags" ng-if="tag.title===n.title">
{{n.name}}
</span>
</div>
```

the first loop is looping on all unique `allTags` based on their description

the second inner loop loops on `allTags` and gets the tag which has the same title as the outer loop to display the name

notice the `$index` is used in loops to distinct each iterate to provide a diffrent id for each one

i didn`t test the above code but the logic is like that

**Edit**

`unique` filter is an add-on in angular-ui [solved here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16827300/unknown-provider-uniquefilterprovider-using-unique-filter-in-angular-js)

Comment: could it be that I have to use some special service to use unique filter? I got error Unknown provider: uniqueFilterProvider <- uniqueFilter

Comment: my fault you need a refrence for this
angular-filter

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16827300/unknown-provider-uniquefilterprovider-using-unique-filter-in-angular-js

Comment: Yes I allready did that. Its working thank you, though there was small syntax error - $index should be ir {{}}

Comment: glad to help out

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the [`ngRepeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) directive like so:

```
<div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="tag in allTags track by $index">
  <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
      <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse{{tag.id}}" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse{{tag.id}}">
        {{tag.title}}        
      </a>
    </h4>
  </div>
  <div id="collapse{{tag.id}}" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <p>{{tag.name}}</p>
      <p>{{tag.description}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This way you loop through each tag in `allTags` and can then access the value of each `tag` using the double curly brace notation `{{ }}`.

### Here is a working example:

```js
// app.js
(function() {

  'use strict';

  angular.module('app', []);


})();

// main.controller.js
(function() {

  angular.module('app').controller('MainController', MainController);

  MainController.$inject = ['$scope'];

  function MainController($scope) {

    $scope.allTags = [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'name1',
        description: 'description1',
        title: 'title1'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'name2',
        description: 'description2',
        title: 'title2'
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'name3',
        description: 'description3',
        title: 'title3'
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        name: 'name4',
        description: 'description4',
        title: 'title4'
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        name: 'name5',
        description: 'description5',
        title: 'title5'
      },
      {
        id: 6,
        name: 'name6',
        description: 'description6',
        title: 'title6'
      },
      {
        id: 7,
        name: 'name7',
        description: 'description7',
        title: 'title7'
      },
    ];

  }

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController as MainCtrl">

  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
    <div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="tag in allTags track by $index">
      <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse{{tag.id}}" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse{{tag.id}}">
            {{tag.title}}        
          </a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse{{tag.id}}" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <p>{{tag.name}}</p>
          <p>{{tag.description}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```